# Set up Yeelight (Color) in both Yeelight an MiHome app

Tags: smart-home

I have recently purchased a Xiaomi Gateway with body motion sensors for automating lights in my house. I already had a couple of Yeelight Led Bulb (YLDP02YL) set up with the Yeelight app, in which I had created different scenes (afternoon, night, TV, etc).

The problem is that, for automating them with the MiHome app, I had to reset them and configure them with it. This app does not have the same options as Yeelight and since I reset the bulbs I cannot use the Yeelight app anymore. So now I cannot change both bulbs to TV mode with just selecting the scene. I have to go one by one (and choose a favorite color/brightness).

Does anybody know if it is possible to have the Yeelight Led bulbs in both apps? It's a pity that there is no way to create scenes in MiHome app and lose that feature from Yeelight app :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that my Yeelight Led bulbs were set up in a different server than my account in MiHome. I didn't even remember I had to choose a server when I got them. Setting them up in the same server solved my problem :)